# Tool for finding namespace dependencies in my project?

Tags: c#, namespaces, dependencies

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) seems to be a good tool for finding module (DLL) dependencies. But what if I have all these "modules" in the same assembly, separated by namespace like below?

```
namespace Root.ModuleA { ... }
namespace Root.ModuleB { ... }
namespace Root.ModuleC { ... }
```

Does a tool exist that can find out namespace dependencies inside my assembly, e.g. that `Root.ModuleC` uses stuff in `Root.ModuleA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the *tijmenvdk* note, two default rules (over LINQ queries, CQLinq) are proposed concerning namespace dependency cycle:

- [Avoid namespaces dependency cycles](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_namespaces_dependency_cycles.html)
- [Avoid namespaces mutually dependent](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Avoid_namespaces_mutually_dependent.html)

You can try these rules on your code now, NDepend proposes a [free time-limited full-featured trial edition](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx). Then you can export dependencies between namespaces to a dependency graph or a dependency matrix (the matrix is better suited if you have dozens of namespaces):

[image: CQLinq query for namespaces dependency cycles]

The [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) could look like (notice the namespaces in red entangled in a cycles):

[image: Dependency Graph with namespaces dependency cycle]

The [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) could look like (notice the cycle highlighted with a red square)

[image: Dependency Matrix with namespaces dependency cycle]

To go further you can read [these two whitebooks](http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) on partitioning .NET code through assemblies and namespaces. Also recently Hendry Luk wrote a complete [blog post](http://hendryluk.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/sheepaop-code-review-with-ndepend-part-i/) about getting rid of namespaces dependency cycles in its project SheepAop.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)?

Comment: The default CQL (code query language) statements include a check for namespace dependency cycles out of the box. Right-click on the results and you get the cycle visualized in the matrix or dependency graph.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio's [Architecture Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409431.aspx) does a pretty good job of that. There is a [dependency graph specific to namesspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx).

Comment: It sounds great, except for the need for VS Ultimate.

Comment: Dang. I forget that piece. It's too bad as it is a very nice tool.

Answer (score 1):

[nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is probably the best tool for this job.

The dependency matrix view will show you all namespaces and how they related to each other.